# more parameters in constructor of subclass in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, class-constructors

I am newbie . 
I want add age parameter in Employee class drived from Person class. how can I do that in kotlin?!

```
abstract class Person constructor (var name :String ,var gender :String) {
}
```

I got error with this way:

```
class Employee() : Person() {
    constructor(age : Int ) : super (name , gender)
}
```

and why can not use var or val in Employee constructor?!
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use primary constructor for that:

```
class Employee(name: String, gender: String, val age: Int) : Person(name, gender) {}
```

When you have a primary constructor with some parameters in a parent class, you should specify the same constructor in its subclass plus additional parameters if need.